# convert a raster (.tif format) into a mesh

Tags: raster, point-cloud, cloudcompare

I want to use the cloud to mesh registration tools in Cloud Compare to align a raster (.tif format) to a point cloud (.las format) for surface differencing. what is the best raster to mesh conversion to use?

Comment: Other way around is more efficient, I.. interpolate points